# So i have a json file how i can insert it in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm looking to make a php script to update the mysql every hour from a json file.

the api is that

http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=51f7eb704bd7b8231900000c&appid=730&format=json

How i can copy this things from json and put them in the mysql?

I mean something like that

```
"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 34,
    "value": 2268
},

"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 21,
    "value": 9386
},
"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 55,
    "value": 4968
},
"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 40,
    "value": 6018
},
"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Well-Worn)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 40,
    "value": 3597
},
"AK-47 | Black Laminate (Battle-Scarred)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 50,
    "value": 345
},
"AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 8,
    "value": 8593
},
"AK-47 | Black Laminate (Field-Tested)": {
    "last_updated": 1436569230,
    "quantity": 141,
    "value": 308
},
```

I want this to go in the mysql like that

[image]

This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=51f7eb704bd7b8231900000c&appid=730&format=json');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

//Database Connection
require_once 'db.php';

/* insert data into DB */
foreach($obj as $item) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cyberst_CSGO`.`items` ( cost, lastupdate)
   VALUES ('".$item['value']."'', '".$item['last_updated']."')");

}
//database connection close
mysql_close($con);

//}
?>
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: use a `foreach` loop that goes through the array, and performs an `INSERT` for each item.

Comment: @jeff http://pastebin.com/cKf1XvtS

Comment: Maybe post the PHP code so we can help a little more?

Comment: I'm new at this i never tried something similar

Comment: in your provided code you missed, that the data you need is in 3rd level of your json (and then your array). So you'd have to change the iteration to: `foreach($obj['response']['items'] as $item) { ...`

Comment: @jeff thank you but i cant load the php script when i try to load it its giving me an error 
Error 524 A timeout occurred (Broswer time's out)

Comment: have you debugged your code? somethings like `print_r($obj)`, printing the sql-statement? then you can figure out have far you get...

Comment: I dont know how to do that :/ @jeff I want to copy this "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)" and paste it in to name area "last_updated": 1436569230, in the lastupdated area and     "value": 2268 in the cost area so it will look like that http://prntscr.com/7r9udc and repeat the same and for the other items

Comment: try `print_r($obj)` to see if you have the correct data in first place. then change your `foreach` as I suggested. then write `$sql = "INSERT INTO `cyberst_CSGO`.`items` ( cost, lastupdate)
       VALUES ('".$item['value']."'', '".$item['last_updated']."')"; echo $sql;` in that loop to see how far you get.

Comment: When i tried to add the print_r($obj) the page became empty

Comment: can anyone paste a entire code for this? I really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This code generates a temporary tab-delimited file and uses `LOAD DATA IN FILE` to insert that file into the database then deletes the temporary file.

1. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) - mysql functions are deprecated in PHP now
2. EDIT: `cost = value * 0.01`.
3. Fastest way to load a bunch of data into MySQL is with [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
4. I haven't tested the database import but I've used this method many times and it works quite well.
5. You may need to escape `$name $cost $row` with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `$conn->real_escape_string()` first. I didn't check all your data.

Here's the PHP:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=51f7eb704bd7b8231900000c&appid=730&format=json');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

//open a temporary file to hold data
$path  = str_replace('\\','/',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$filename = time().'tmp.csv';
$filename = $path.'/'.$filename;
$tmpfile = fopen($filename,'w+');

//data to loop through and write to temporary file
$loopme = $obj['response']['items'];

foreach($loopme as $name=>$row) {
    //i'm guessing this is what cost is
    $cost = $row['value'] * 0.01;
    //write to our tmp file
    fwrite($tmpfile,"$name\t$cost\t$row[last_updated]\n");
}

// this is the fastest way to load large amounts of data into MySQL
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'
  INTO TABLE `cyberst_CSGO`.`items`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

//run your mysql query

//delete temporary file
unlink($filename);
```

Comment: so the php should look like that http://pastebin.com/ZBctbUXW and the database file like that http://pastebin.com/G82eEdPy ? Or i'm doing something wrong when i use that codes i'm getting empty page

Comment: If the data is loading as expected in the database it's probably working as expected. As is right now there are no echo statements in that code. So output whatever you want. I didn't write the code to actually run the query

Comment: No- you're not setting up to run the query stored in $sql. I think you need to read a basic how to on [mysqli](http://codular.com/php-mysqli). I provided only the code to process the json data into a file and the SQL to load it into MySQL

Comment: but when i run (standalone the script) is not creating any temp file anywhere Any idea how i can find the file?

Comment: It's deleting the file at the last line (once you finish the query) if you want to see the file just comment out the unlink line. The temp file is just there for MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` query

Comment: No file created. ( http://prntscr.com/7s8zeu ) I removed this line. unlink($filename);

Comment: What did the PHP file say when you visited? (Check the page source too) Maybe we can chat somewhere about this instead of a long comment list here...

Comment: Alright (my email is ursus445@gmail.com (If you can sent me a message) (When i click view source) the page is empty.