# Find closest integer in Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

as the title says I'm trying to find the closest integer in an Object, I have my data stored in the following way, I can not change the way it's stored.

```
{"response":
    {"success":1,"current_time":1490650140,"items":
        {"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)":{"last_updated":1490648718,"quantity":98,"value":1120},
        "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)":{"last_updated":1490648718,"quantity":47,"value":3229},
        "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)":{"last_updated":1490648718,"quantity":159,"value":1623}
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to find the item that's the closest to a given number (x). If items are worth equal it should just pick either. I know I'd be needing a loop for this but I have no idea where to begin.

I'm trying to find the closest integer x to value in the obj.

Comment: So reference the array, do a for loop. Store the value, if lower, overwrite and store the next value.

Comment: That what I was thinking but isn't there a more efficient way to do it..?

Comment: "efficient"?  No.   "Cleaner"?  Perhaps...

Comment: This [data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31351802/215552) set seems to be [awfully](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42913815/215552) [popular](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37033695/215552).

Comment: Also, this will only get me the highest value, not the closest.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it's an API used by many sites.

Comment: So you do the calculation to find the closest...

Comment: Which integers are relevant? For example, would the `success` value of `1` be valid for consideration? What about the `last_updated` values? Or the `47` in `AK-47`?

Comment: I only need to know for ex which value of which item is the closest to 1000. Which in this case should be the (Battle-Scarred) version.

Comment: Why don't you try to code this yourself? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I'm trying but my json loop isn't even working, my console keeps saying whenever I try to get data this way, prices.response.items[0].value is undefined while it can't be.. @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for..in` over the object, or use array iterating methods `for`, `.forEach`, etc. by working with `Object.keys(data.response.items)` (which will give you an array of Object keys).

```js
const data = {"response":
    {"success":1,"current_time":1490650140,"items":
        {"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)":{"last_updated":1490648718,"quantity":98,"value":1120},
        "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)":{"last_updated":1490648718,"quantity":47,"value":3229},
        "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)":{"last_updated":1490648718,"quantity":159,"value":1623}
        }
    }
};
const target = 1344;

function findClosestForIn(items, target) {
    let closestVal = Infinity;
    let closestObj = null;

    for (let key in items) {
        let obj = items[key];
        let curDiff = Math.abs(obj.value - target);

        if (curDiff < closestVal) {
          closestVal = curDiff;
          closestObj = obj;
        }
    }

    return closestObj;
}

function findClosestObjectKeys(items, target) {
    let closestVal = Infinity;
    let closestObj = null;

    Object.keys(data.response.items).forEach((key) => {
        const obj = data.response.items[key];
        const curDiff = Math.abs(obj.value - target);

        if (curDiff < closestVal) {
          closestVal = curDiff;
          closestObj = obj;
        }
    });

    return closestObj;
}


console.log('closest using for..in: ', findClosestForIn(data.response.items, target));
console.log('closest using Object.keys: ', findClosestObjectKeys(data.response.items, target));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variable to store the closest match.

You can use JsonObject to handle the parsing of the json.

Load the first entry into the variable.
Loop through the rest of the entries and check each one against the previously-stored one.  If it's closer to your search figure, replace the stored one with this one.

It's basically the same problem as finding the highest or lowest value in a list, except that you use a different formula to decide when to replace your previously-stored value with a new one.

Comment: Okay I get that, but how can I check if one is closer than an other integer.

Comment: if (Math.abs(searchValue - thisJsonObject.getInt("last_update") < Math.abs(searchValue - best.getInt("last_update")) { best = thisJsonObject; }

Comment: I can't just not work it out, I'm trying to get the json objects by int but it doesn't seem to be working at all.